# Wordpress single sign on using cookies with shared user role functionality between more than 2 wordpress subdomains

Tags: multisite, user-roles

I have more than 2 wordpress subdomains. Before this, I tried using wordpress multisite, but my hosting doesn't has wildcard subdomain. I want to manually change subdomain directory to be appointed on public html, but my hosting doesn't has that functionality too. So my last option is to make single sign on using cookies. I have created custom user table anda custom user meta, also created same cookies path between 2 of my wordpress sites, following this tutorial: https://jeffmikels.org/posts/single-sign-on-for-multiple-wordpress-installations/
I have success, but there is a problem. When I log in into second wordpress, I doesn't have a same role as my first site. Do you guys have a solution so I can create sso with shared user role for 2 or more wordpress subdomains? Thanks.

Comment: if you read the comments section on the tutorial in your question, there is mention of the problem of capabilities and a potential solution. This might what you are looking for? I suppose you could come up with a way to automatically sync the capabilities (copy the user meta from one key to another) on login.

Comment: I think using custom user meta is just same with copy the user meta from one key to another. I already try anything to make this thing work, but still the result is not like what I had expected.

Comment: suggest adding the code you are using to try to do that to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to use a plugin instead,

https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/configure-single-sign-on-for-multiple-wordpress-sites-and-make-it-secure

have a look at this and this one
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multisite-sso/

hope this might help

Comment: I need plugin with multiuser functionality too. All of plugin that I met just have SSO, but the user that come into second site just login as quest, even the administrator from first site.

Comment: ok, how about this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/worpit-admin-dashboard-plugin/   it has "Automatically log into your WordPress sites without remembering your WordPress login details." this feature. Also, what i guess with your situation, you need to have look into this one as well, https://developer.wordpress.com/calypso/    it's a new project from wordpress team.